# Tic Tac Toe Reset button in java

Tags: java, jtextarea, tic-tac-toe

I have added a button to rest the game but i don't know how to add a listener to that or how to call a method when i click on the button. Please show me how to get the reset button working. Thank you.

```
   private String[] board = new String[ 9 ]; // tic-tac-toe board
   private JTextArea outputArea; // for outputting moves
   private Player[] players; // array of Players
  private ServerSocket server; // server socket to connect with clients
  private int currentPlayer; // keeps track of player with current move
  private final static int PLAYER_X = 0; // constant for first player
   private final static int PLAYER_O = 1; // constant for second player
  private final static String[] MARKS = { "X", "O" }; // array of marks
  private ExecutorService runGame; // will run players
  private Lock gameLock; // to lock game for synchronization
  private Condition otherPlayerConnected; // to wait for other player
  private Condition otherPlayerTurn; // to wait for other player's turn
  private boolean win;
 public TicTacToeServer()
  {
  super( "Tic-Tac-Toe Server" ); // set title of window

  // create ExecutorService with a thread for each player
  runGame = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 );
  gameLock = new ReentrantLock(); // create lock for game

  // condition variable for both players being connected
  otherPlayerConnected = gameLock.newCondition();

  // condition variable for the other player's turn
  otherPlayerTurn = gameLock.newCondition();      

  for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
     board[ i ] = new String( "" ); 
  players = new Player[ 2 ]; // create array of players
  currentPlayer = PLAYER_X; // set current player to first player

  try
  {
     server = new ServerSocket( 12345, 2 ); // set up ServerSocket
  } // end try
  catch ( IOException ioException ) 
  {
     ioException.printStackTrace();
     System.exit( 1 );
  } // end catch

  outputArea = new JTextArea(); // create JTextArea for output
  add( outputArea, BorderLayout.CENTER );
  JButton reset= new JButton ("Reset");
  add(reset, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  reset.setActionCommand("reset");
  //reset.addActionListener(this);
  outputArea.setText( "Server awaiting connections\n" );


  setSize( 300, 300 ); // set size of window
  setVisible( true ); // show window
  } // end TicTacToeServer constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use ActionListener:

Register it to the button and an implementation will contain the code that will be called automatically once the button is clicked. 
This is how java event system works.

Here is a tutorial [Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can add an action listner simply like this

```
   reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         //Execute when button is pressed
      }        
    });
```

Comment: I add the listener and the execute but nothing happens:                     
                reset.setActionCommand("reset");
               reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                  {
           for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
                  board[ i ] = new String( "" ); 
               players = new Player[ 2 ]; 
               currentPlayer = PLAYER_X;  player
                       }        
                      });

Comment: how are you repainting the board when a player makes a turn.